# Populate second dropdown based on first - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-options

I have two `select` boxes. The first one contains report names and the second one (which should populate dynamically based on report name `select` box) contains format options.

I want to populate format `select` box with corresponding formats when I `select` report names.

I have defined formats for reports in an array as follows

```
$scope.reportOptions = [{
    "reportName": "Cash Position",
    "reportValue": "Cash Position Report",
    "formats": ["CSV", "PDF", "XLS"]
}, {
    "reportName": "Detail Report",
    "reportValue": "Detail Report",
    "formats": ["CSV", "PDF", "XLS"]
}, {
    "reportName": "Reconciliation Report",
    "reportValue": "Reconciliation Report",
    "formats": ["BAI", "CSV", "PDF", "QBO", "QFX", "XLS"]
}, {
    "reportName": "Summary Report",
    "reportValue": "Summary Report",
    "formats": ["BAI", "CSV", "PDF", "XLS"]
}, {
    "reportName": "Sweep Report",
    "reportValue": "Sweep Report",
    "formats": ["CSV", "PDF", "XLS"]
}, {
    "reportName": 'Custom Report Name',
    "reportValue": 'CustomReport',
    "formats": ["BAI", "CSV", "PDF", "QBO", "QFX", "XLS"]
}];
```

My filter is as follows

```
.filter('exportTypeFilter', function() {
    return function(input, selectedreport, scope) {
        var selectedReportFormatOptions = [];
        var output = $.grep(scope.reportOptions, function(e) {
            return e["reportValue"] == selectedreport;
        });
        selectedReportFormatOptions = output[0]["formats"];
        return selectedReportFormatOptions;
    };
})
```

The values are not getting populated into the `select` box. What wrong am I doing?

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/nwn838yb/4/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `exportTypeFilter` filter is returning `undefined` value. When it runs for the first time the `selectedreport` argument in filter is passed as `""`(empty string) due to which the `var output` evaluates to `undefined`.

Added `ng-init="interactor.parameters.reportName = 'Cash Position Report'"` in first `select` box to fix the problem

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nwn838yb/5/

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your `jsfiddle` a bit.

Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/nwn838yb/1/

Basically you even don't need a filter to achieve what you want. You need a variable tied to your scope in which selected object from the first select will be stored. For that I have added `$scope.selectedReport = {};` to your scope.

Then, in your select you need to iterate through `$scope.reportOptions` and save user selection to `selectedReport`. To do this, you simply define `ng-model="selectedReport"` - it tells in which variable user selection will be stored and `ng-options="report.reportName for report in reportOptions"` - this tells "Please iterate through reportOptions, for options simply show reportName  and if user selects something, just store selected object".

For example, user have selected "Cash Position". This object will be stored in `selectedReport`:

```
{
   "reportName":"Cash Position",
   "reportValue":"Cash Position Report",
   "formats":["CSV","PDF","XLS"]
}
```

Using this object, you can populate and iterate through `selectedReport.format` similarly to the first select.

Comment: This is great, but could you add some explanation to your answer and not just rely on OP scouring the fiddle.

Comment: Your `select` `option value` in report `select` box returns an `object` which I don't want. I have specifically given two different properties in `reportOptions` for the `option text` and `option value` as `reportName` and `reportValue`. Look at your value here: https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/nwn838yb/2/

Comment: @Nishant123 you can simply get your values by calling `selectedReport.reportName` or `selectedReport.reportValue`: https://jsfiddle.net/nwn838yb/3/